# Shortcode and variable

Tags: plugins, shortcode, variables

I need some help, this may be a noob question, I am trying to add a string variable into my short code. Here is what I have so far:

```
$instagram_title = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'instagram_title', true);
if(isset($instagram_title) && $instagram_title != "") :
    echo do_shortcode("[easy-instagram limit=2 caption_hashtags=false caption_char_limit=0 author_text='' thumb_click='thickbox' time_text='' thumb_size=220px tag='" .$instagram_title. "']");
endif;
```

My ultimate goal is to utilize the "$instagram_title" so that I don't have to create a ton of widgets for each page in the site.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes across this in the future, here is what I figured out:

```
$askavl_instagram_contact_title = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'askavl_instagram_contact_title', true);
if(isset($askavl_instagram_contact_title) && $askavl_instagram_contact_title != "") :
    $tag = str_replace("#","", ((string)$askavl_instagram_contact_title) );
    $thumbsize = "220px";
    $image_limit = "2";
    $easyInstagramSC = "[easy-instagram limit={$image_limit} caption_hashtags=false caption_char_limit=0 author_text='' thumb_click='thickbox' time_text='' thumb_size={$thumbsize} tag='{$tag}']";
    echo do_shortcode( $easyInstagramSC );
```

From what I can tell my error was in the concatenation. This is working, hoewever if someone knows a better solution I would like to improve this.